# Confusing Usage Of 'Apparent'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammar, adjectives

I just stumbled across the following sentence in Brightness Falls by Jay McInerny:

> Having until a month before been heir apparent, Russell was going to have to think seriously about getting a new job, or something.

I can't figure out the meaning of 'apparent' here, as an adjective, to which substantive does it belong?

Comment: Hint: look up *heir apparent*.

Comment: You should always consult an English language dictionary before asking a question about the meaning of a word or phrase. The phrase _heir apparent_ is defined in at least 23 easily available online English dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Heir apparent* is a fixed phrase with a meaning that isn't obvious from its two parts.

From Wikipedia,

> An heir apparent ... is a person who is first in line of succession and cannot be displaced from inheriting by the birth of another person.

Comment: But, the meaning *is* obvious from the parts.  The heir apparent is the person who seems likely to inherit.  The oddity is the old-fashioned word order.  If there were no long-standing legal history of using that exact phrase, the modern phrasing could easily be "the apparent heir".

Comment: I don't think it's totally obvious. For example, when Elizabeth of Great Britain was apparently the heir, she was not the heir apparent, because if her parents had had a son, that son would have become the heir.